# delete an element from an array with conditions python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, remove-if

i have 3 array a and b with the same size

```
a= [1,20,0,3,9,9,9,55]
b= [1,5,6,9,9,9,9,55]
```

i need to delete the element 0 from a and delete the element in the same index in the array b will look like this:

```
    a= [1,20,3,9,9,9,55]
    b= [1,5,9,9,9,9,55]



import numpy as np
import math
a = np.array([1, 0,3])
b = np.array([5, 6,9])


c= np.vstack((a,b)).T
c= c[(c[:,0]<>0)]
k= c[:,0]
f= c[:,1]
r= math.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(((k - f) / k),2)))
r
```

my code is working but i did not like it do you have any other propositions ?

Comment: There's a dedicated site for code reviews http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

if you have a, b, c  as numpy arrays

```
valid_idx = (a != 0)
b = b[valid_idx]
c = c[valid_idx]
```